# Pass vector of inherited class object to function expecting base class vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I am working with a class A, which inherits from opencv Rect. A just adds some variables I would like to keep track during execution.

```
class A: public Rect { //code, constructors... }
```

I want to use the opencv method `detectMultiScale` which expects an empty `vector<Rect>` and what does is fill it with the expected output.

How can I pass an empty vector of inherited objects, that's it the  `vector<A>` from Rect and expect to catch the base class inside the method? (I understand at this point that the method is a black box, I don't want to compile opencv to redeclare something).

Comment: A `vector<Rect>` and a `vector<A>` are two totally dfferent types.  If the function wants a `vector<Rect>`, you need to send it a `vector<Rect>`, nothing else.

Comment: In addition, why are you deriving from a `Rect` when it is not meant to be derived from.  If `Rect` had a virtual destructor, that's one thing, but the designers of `Rect` never meant it to be used for the purposes you're using it for.  Maybe the `Rect` should be a member of `A` instead of deriving `A` from `Rect`.

Comment: Like Paul says, it seems you are misusing public inheritance. It is far more likely that `A` must either *own* a `Rect` or be associated with one by some other means.

Comment: My previous scheme was a class owning a rect, I thought I could just extend. Back to old (but correct) design.

Comment: Google "a bag of apples is not a bag of fruit".

Comment: So, somebody writes an answer to close the question :)

Comment: If the performance isn't going to hurt, you could coalesce all of the Rects into a vector when needed, and then call the function using that vector.  Or you can take the more dangerous route of creating a `vector<Rect>` and have each `A` have  a pointer to one of the items in the `vector<Rect>` -- the caveat is that you need to ensure the vector never gets resized, since pointers to elements in the vector may become invalidated on resize.

Comment: Well the performance is critical. The current approach using the class with `Rect` as a member of `A` is to work with `vector<Rect>`, fill it inside `detectMultiScale` and create `vector<A>` object by object. In fact the vector is not resized after it has been filled from `detectMultiScale`

Comment: @AlejandroSazo, what aspect of performance is critical here? If copying the `Rect`s is that costly, store indexes into the `std::vector` in `A`. And stash the vector itself somewhere.

Comment: the `detectMultiScale` is inside a loop receiving real time information. Each iteration has a "Rect-to-A" process, for each `Rect` I create a new `A` and push_back it to the vector. I can get the `vector<Rect>` size and make a vector with that size, then use myvector[i] = Rect instead of push back each time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass an empty vector of inherited objects, that's it the vector from Rect and expect to catch the base class inside the method?

This is not possible. The function expects a vector of `Rect` objects, so that is what you must pass.

If you want to have a vector of `A`, then you can write a constructor `A(Rect)`, that accepts an instance of the base class as an argument, and initializes the base sub object accordingly. Then write a loop that transforms the aquired `Rect` instances.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that won't work, you'll have to work with `std::vector<Rect*>` - intuitively, this follows when `sizeof(Rect) != sizeof(A)`, so even your indexing will fail, let alone class layout, for `std::vector<Rect>`. Either pointers, or, if you have a fixed set of types, you can experiment with variant and visitors.

EDIT: If your use case (`detectMultiScale`) does not allow you to pass `vector<std::Rect*>`, you might choose from the various decorator-visitor implementations. In this case, you have to give up direct inheritance. To name some:

- Have a `std::vector<Rect>` and a `std::vector<ARectV>`. `ARectV` contains the additional fields that you can't find in `Rect`.

  - you might add a ref to the corresponding (visited) `Rect` if you wish. In this case, the constructor will fill Rect; or
  - your `ARectV` methods might take a (possibly const) `Rect&`, in this case your constructor doesn't need to store it
- If all else fails, have a static `std::map<Rect*, ARectV> sARectV`. This will be slower and needs manual insertion / deletion (possibly in constructors / destructor of sARectV, the former taking a - possibly const - `Rect*` or `Rect&`), but allows you to write: `sARectV[&rect].yourfunction()`. Of course, it also allows for standard notation, that is, `Rect rect; ARectV rectv(rect); rectv.yourfunction();` - but you might not be able to pass `rv` to callbacks that should take `Rect*` or `Rect&`. If they take `Rect` by value, you're out of luck.

Comment: `sizeof(Rect) != sizeof(A)` that may in fact not be the case. If a class adds no members, its size is the same as its base. It is however correct not to assume it in the general case.

Comment: Also, in the context of `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale` (see OP), using `vector<Rect*>` simply won't work.

Comment: @StoryTeller: edited to fix that. Also, on practically all architectures I ever worked with, iff there are no additional non-static fields (incl. virtuals - new or overloaded) and no other non-empty base classes (and the `sizeof` criteria holds), this will sort of work - but still UB, so don't tell it to anyone :) This is due to how memory is organized.

Comment: @StoryTeller: edited according to 2nd comment, thanks.

Comment: @StoryTeller Or more accurately, adds no member variables, and only reuses pre-existing base class vtables.